# Sage not displaying/rendering 3D plots (Partially solved)

Tags: python-3.x, plot, jupyter-notebook, rendering, sage

## partially solved : Works in jmol trough Sage CLI

### 3D plot remains blank in SageMath in Jupyter Notebook

Edit: This problem still remains unsolved, I have tried to even boot into a different OS  (Debian instead of Kali) (not using anaconda, will (hopefully) get more time to try that)

As the title describes and illustrated by this screenshot:

[image: Command for 3D plot produces white instead of interactive 3D plot]

Instead of the expected 3D plot, just a white plain background with a question mark in it, that, when clicked, displays a menu like this:

[image: Menu obtained when clicking the empty plot]

I have now experimented quite a bit on this example (on my system) and... to give an example:

This shows just a black square (while it's supposed to show a sphere):

```
sage: u = var('u')
sage: circle = (cos(u), sin(u))
sage: rp = revolution_plot3d
sage: rp(circle, (u, 0, 2*pi), axis=(0, 0),
....:    show_curve=True, opacity=0.5).show(aspect_ratio=(1, 1, 1))
```

The following code is (I guess) *a bit* better, but still not really "as it should be", or "as expected":

```
sage: u = var('u')
sage: circle = (cos(u), sin(u))
sage: rp = revolution_plot3d
sage: rp(circle, (u, 0, 2*pi), axis=(0, 0), frame=False,
....:    show_curve=True, opacity=0.5).show(aspect_ratio=(1, 1, 1))
```

(Change: include `frame=False` somewhere in the last line).

#### Inspiration

I am trying to recreate [this 3D plot from the SageMath documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/revolution_plot3d.html#sage.plot.plot3d.revolution_plot3d.revolution_plot3d):

[image: Sphere 3D plot from SageMath documentation]

### Info/Logs:

- SageMath version:

  ```
  SageMath version 9.2, Release Date: 2020-10-24
  ```
- OS: Kali Linux
- SageMath installed via `apt`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install sagemath
  ```

I do not need to "get" this solved  anytime soon, Right now I am mostly doing matrix operations, and such. so - there is no "hurry" with coming up with a solution here! It would just be a [plus+] to be able to do as the problem describe, but it is not necessary.

**Any** help is **greatly** appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I had a bit problem formatting this question, (not used to it) so,  if it needs/can be improved/be edited,  It's just so say that!/Edit!  It's  very appreciated, too.  Thanks!

Comment: What operating system? How was Sage installed?

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre Hello, thanks so much for replying!  I am (currently) using Kali Linux, Sage was installed using apt  (`sudo apt install sagemath`)  I should mention I have tried starting it from (pressing the "windows" button / super button, and trough terminal by typing `sage -n ` or --notebook (n for notebook) in the current directory I am in

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre Thanks for the editing help; really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MAJOR UPDATE:

To not introduce false hope to the future readers: I have NOT solved it in **Jupyter notebook.**

### **But**

I have (probably) fixed it with a viewer, my system had Jmol pre installed; (probably because I liked it before, and did some exercises with it, as in Matlab)

### The (partial) solution:

But here is the thing, when I access a SAGE terminal (bash -> `sage`) and for example, plotting something **that normally would just result in either white - or a black screen in Jupyter whatever I tried to do to make it work;**

It opens up a jmol window *(the, actual application - Jmol)*

and **plots it.**

I did not know it was this easy to get Jmol and sage math to work together (a actual fact; I did not **even know this was possible**.

### Screenshots

here are a few screenshots (Jupyter - black screen, and the exact same code - but run from `Sage Terminal`

[image: In Jupyter]

### Same code, but in Sage terminal:

(Identical results) (Which, was for me impossible, even at times where I *could*  (In Jupyter)  (ugly)-plot it, it didn't show the expected results, (colors were a bit distorted, and the form had very little in common with the actual plot Sage Docs was showing)

[image: Jmol Window Same code - From Sage Terminal]

To be honest, I think - I like this more, even if Jupyter would've got to work (maybe some time in the future) This - jmol application has some really neat properties, (color, axis's, and animations (rotation) and other stuff) I did really not know this at all; In Jupyter one maybe could rotate it with the mouse and zoom in, but not really change color, easily - (Not saying this is more expected result, but In my opinion - in my **scenario** - This was one, (*)good workaround, **If not a actual solution, (In my case I will continue this way, it's flawless**)

Hopefully this is helpful for someone in the future!

Comment: But - Future (and, previous readers & answeres) Please, thank you all for every help I got;  Still,  maybe doesn't work in Jupyter - But if someone (maybe years after this) comes up with a solution may or may not be in jupyter - ) Please post it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could have to do with the threejs package in Debian that came for the particular version of Sage you got.

You might have better luck installing via Conda or from binaries.

- https://wiki.sagemath.org/Conda
- https://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html

For reference, here is a list of similar reports (including the present one):

- [Stack Overflow question 66584781: Sage not displaying/Rendering 3D plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66584781)
- [Ask Sage question 55896: implicit_plot3d not rendering in Jupyter Lab](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/55896)
- [Ask Sage question 55661: plot3d shows a black window](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/55661)
- [Ask Sage question 52722: plot3d displaying black graph in jupyter for both 9.0 and 9.1](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/52722)
- [debian-science-sagemath, 2019-11: Consider updating package three.js](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/debian-science-sagemath/2019-November/001583.html)

Comment: I should mention; I actively avoid installing anaconda, (even if it would work) because I want only Sage, not anything else (Understand me correctly when I say that) I mean; the Less [additional] programs(and, obviously - it's dependencies) the better, for a majority of reasons, *probably not related in this question*  (Though, I thank you for mentioning it) Will at least look into it :)

Comment: Anaconda brings the Conda package manager together with an important base installation. But other Conda distributions are minimalist, such as Miniconda, Miniforge, Minimamba. See https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases

Comment: Oh, I should say I did not know about these, will **def**. Look into these, and come back with results. Thanks; Still - If there was a way of just correcting this,(by, not installing any additional - program, (Shortly, Just "fixing" the problem) (Obviously, if it is a dependency issue - it cannot be helped)  **EDIT** read your updated post, now I have some stuff to read. Coming back soon, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like the OP (original poster), I had the same error with show3d() in a Jupyter notebook under SageMath 9.6. I was not using JMOL. In SageMath 9.7, compiled from source under Ubunto 20.10 in WSL2 on a Windows 10 system, an attempt to use show3d() in a Jupyter notebook, for example

```
    # Franklin Graph
    Frank = graphs.FranklinGraph()
    Frank.show3d()
```

resulted in the following error.

```
    $HOME/sage/sage-9.7/src/sage/repl/rich_output/display_manager.py:610: 
    RichReprWarning: Exception in _rich_repr_ while displaying object:
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
    '$HOME/sage/local/lib/sage/ext_data/threejs/threejs-version.txt'
    warnings.warn(
```

(reformatted for typographical clarity.)

My workaround was to copy the source from $HOME/sage/sage-9.7/src/sage/ext_data/threejs to $HOME/sage/local/lib/sage/ext_data/threejs.

This is not entirely satisfactory as the directory naming suggests that the installation of threejs did not proceed as intended. I may take this up with the SageMath development list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Adding another answer because this is both quite awhile ago but also, a quite different solution

by adding  `Frame=False`, works flawlessly and to be sure this really, works I have tested this on numerous previous problems I had  previously and it seems to work, I do not know for sure what this is about but, at least it works

```py
u = var('u')
circle = (cos(u), sin(u))
revolution_plot3d(circle, (u,0,2*pi), axis=(0,0), 
                  show_curve=True, opacity=0.5).show(aspect_ratio=(1,1,1),
                                                     frame=False)
```

[image: plot 1]

I also experimented a bit with `opacity=1`

[image: plot 2]